# Set fix values on y-axis vue-chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I use [vue-chartjs](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) as a wrapper for [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/). I had a simple line chart with random data but stuck on how to set fix value to be displayed on the chart's y-axis. Currently I have random data from 0-100. Now, what I want to achieve is just display `0, 50, 100` on the y-axis no matter what the random value is starts from `0-100`.

**Sample Script**

```js
putData: function () {
    this.datacollection = {
        labels: ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
        datasets: [{
            lineTension: 0,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#F2A727',
            pointBackgroundColor:[ '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#F2A727'],
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
        }]
    }
},

getRandomInt: function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (95)) + 5
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to set **`stepSize: 50`** and **`maxTicksLimit: 3`** for y-axis ticks, in your chart options :

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
         stepSize: 50,
         maxTicksLimit: 3
      }
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is correct.
For those intereseted, I post code for latest version of Chart.js

Updated to Chart.js **v3.2.0** (not backwards-compatible with **v2.xx**)

In order to avoid automatic scaling if your random data values are all in the middle range close to 50, do the following:

Add `min: 0` and `max: 100` , so you force chart to show exactly those 3 ticks including the **0**, hence `maxTicksLimit: 3`:

**100**

**50**

**0**

```html
<script>
   // ...

options: {
   scales: {
      y: {
         min: 0,
         max: 150,
         ticks: {
            stepSize: 50,
            maxTicksLimit: 3
         }
      }
   }
};

   // ...
</script>
```

Source: [https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#tick-configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size)

(Be aware that in new versions **v3.xx** `min: 0` and `max: 100` are now located **outside** the ticks-object, whereas in **v2.xx** it used to be inside the ticks-object).